# queryString$ in vb6.0

Tags: post, vb6, azure-web-app-service

Can someone please tell me, what should be the contents of queryString$ in the following function?

```
Private Function PostRequest(queryString$, userid$, key$, body$) As String

    With New WinHttpRequest
        .Open "POST", "https://data.azure-api.net/Senddata?" & queryString, Tr ue
        .SetRequestHeader "userid", userid
        .SetRequestHeader "Key", key
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

        .Send body '<- UTF8-conversion of the body-string happens automatically
            
        If Not .WaitForResponse(10) Then '<- give it 10 seconds timeout
            Debug.Print "http-request timed out..:"
        ElseIf .Status <> 200 Then
            Debug.Print "http-request failed with status: "; .Status & " " & .StatusText
        Else 'success (let's return the string-response)
            PostRequest = .ResponseText 'again, conversion from UTF8 is automatic
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might want to edit your question, as the upper part of the source code is not formatted as such.

Anything after the "?" in a URL like `https://data.azure-api.net/Senddata?` are paramters passed to the called page, typically in the form `paramName1=paramValue1[&paramName2=paramValue2]`

See also: [Wikipedia - Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: Dear Hel O'Ween,

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I know that everything after the "?" are parameters.  Referring to the following code, I want to send an xml file to azure-api.net using vb6.0 but I don't know what the value of parameter queryString$ should have and this is my question. Can you please help me?

Comment: This is my code: Private Function PostRequest(queryString$, userid$, key$, body$) As String
With New WinHttpRequest
.Open "POST", "https://data.azure-api.net/Senddata?" & queryString, True
.SetRequestHeader "userid", userid
.SetRequestHeader "Key", key
.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

     .Send body '<- UTF8-conversion of the body-string happens automatically
        
     If Not .WaitForResponse(10) Then '<- give it 10 seconds timeout
        Debug.Print "http-request timed out..:"
     ElseIf .Status <> 200 Then

Comment: Debug.Print "http-request timed out..:"
     ElseIf .Status <> 200 Then
        Debug.Print "http-request failed with status: "; .Status & " " & .StatusText
     Else 'success (let's return the string-response)
        PostRequest = .ResponseText 'again, conversion from UTF8 is automatic
     End If
   End With
 End Function

Comment: @Bill, Reposting the code from the original question into comments isn't helpful.  And said code, by the way, apparently copied from [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?893699-code-conversion-from-vb-net-to-vb6-0&p=5539505&viewfull=1#post5539505). But if you want to "send an xml file" that would more likely be sent in the body, not a query parameter. But xml? The api likely expects json, not xml, refer to the api documentation for requirements and abilities. If xml is to be sent, then the content type probably needs to be "application/xml" or "text/xml", again see the api specs.